# How to stop Event on WPF dataGrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I wanna stop a Event on WPF DataGrid what we do such as

```
this.listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

on WindowsForms.

I couldn't do it by this.

```
dataGrid1_SelectedCellsChanged -= new Action<object, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs>;
```

I use Visual Studio 2017 community and C#.

Could you tell me the way?

THANKS Rafal!

Comment: `dataGrid1_SelectedCellsChanged` is not an event at all

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement unclear, however,

you can simply avoid registering the event in XAML i.e. remove the clause like **SelectedCellsChanged="DataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged"** from XAML.

Or

if you want to unregister the event from the code behind whenever you want, add the following line.

**dataGrid1.SelectedCellsChanged -= DataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged;**

Comment: It's great, Praboda! I did it.